# Material UI in React: make <Paper> Component clickable

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui, dom-events

I want to make a Paper component clickeable. How can I achieve this? I tried setting an id property in the  tag like () and then using the DOM to add an event listener but it does not work. I'm stuck and out of ideas on how to add a click to the Paper component.
Please note that Paper is a div so I don't get why I can't add a click event. Thanks.
My code:

```
<span>
      <Grid item xs={12} sm={12} md={6} lg={4} xl={4} spacing={5} key={something}>
        <Paper className={classes.paper} onClick={}>
             ....
        </Paper>
      </Grid>
</span>
```

Comment: You can't. Paper can't be clicked. CHeck the docs on material ui.
Also, why would you like to click on paper? Paper makes the background color different, just for styles.

Comment: @TigranPetrosyan I can think in a variety of examples, for instance the Google Docs interface, which has a button to start a new empty file. The button looks closer to the MUI Paper component.

Answer (score 1):

Try wrapping the paper component using `IconButton`:

```
<span>
    <Grid item xs={12} sm={12} md={6} lg={4} xl={4} spacing={5} key={something}>
        <IconButton>
            <Paper className={classes.paper} onClick={}>
                 ....
            </Paper>
        </IconButton>
    </Grid>
</span>
```

Answer (score 0):

As @TigranPetrosyan said, they're not intended to be displayed like buttons, but you can use `Card` components which look similar to `Paper`, but can be clickable.

```js
<span>
  <Grid item xs={12} sm={12} md={6} lg={4} xl={4} spacing={5} key={something}>
    <Card sx={{ maxWidth: 345 }}>
      <CardActionArea>
        <CardContent onClick={() => console.log('Clicked!')}>
          <Typography gutterBottom variant="h5" component="div">
            Lizard
          </Typography>
          <Typography variant="body2" color="text.secondary">
            Lizards are a widespread group of squamate reptiles, with over 6,000
            species, ranging across all continents except Antarctica
          </Typography>
        </CardContent>
      </CardActionArea>
    </Card>
  </Grid>
</span>
```

Example taken from the [V5 docs](https://mui.com/material-ui/react-card/), I just added the `onClick` event listener.

[image: Edit hardcore-panini-txq3bq]